# Why does using string instead of auto fix this error?

Tags: c++

When I run the code below, it gives this error:

```
error: request for member 'length' in 'st', which is of non-class type 'const char*'

cout << st.length ();
```

However if I used string instead of auto It runs without errors

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto st="hello" ;
    
    cout << st.length();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because string literals (which are __not__ of type `std::string`) have no `length` method.

Comment: `"hello"` is a string literal, which is represented as an array of six `const char`, which is implicitly convertable to a `const char *`.    While a string literal CAN be converted to `std::string`, rules of the language require preferring to convert to basic types (like pointers) over converting to a class type.   So `auto` deduces the type as `const char *` which is not a class at all, so doesn't have any member function (named `length()` or anything else).   When you specify the type as `std::string`,  the string literal is converted to `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"hello"`, being a string literal, is of type `const char*`, not `std::string`.

When you do this:

```
auto st = "hello";
```

The type of `st` is deduced as `const char*`, not `std::string`.

When you do this instead:

```
string st = "hello";
```

It invokes `std::string`'s constructor that takes in a `const char*` pointer, which will copy the `char`s from the literal into the new `std::string` instance.

Comment: `"hello"` is actually a `const char[6]` which decays into a `const char*` when you assign it to a variable.

Comment: You can also use `string_literals` in C++14, i.e. `"hello"s`.